# Google Charts and HTA : script error https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, hta

I want to use Google Charts dynamically in a HTA. The code works fine as a HTML file. But when I use it in an HTA I get a script error on the line : https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js.

Does anybody know how to solve this? Is it possible to use Google Charts in a HTA (dynamically)?

This my code in HTML

```
<html>
 <head>
 <!--Load the AJAX API-->
 <script type="text/javascript"src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
   var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
   var x =   Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
   data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
   data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
   data.addRows([
    ['Mushrooms', x],
    ['Onions', 1],
    ['Olives', 1],
    ['Zucchini', 1],
    ['Pepperoni', 2]
   ]);

   var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
   'width':1000,
   'height':750};
   var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
   chart.draw(data, options);
   }
  </script>
 </head>
<body>
<!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
<div id="chart_div">
</div>
<div>
 <button onclick="drawChart()">draw</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In my HTA I only add the HTA tag

```
<html>
 <head>
  <HTA:APPLICATION ID="Test Google Charts" 
       BORDER="thick" 
       BORDERSTYLE="complex"/>
  <!--Load the AJAX API-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
   var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
   var x =   Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
   data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
   data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
   data.addRows([
    ['Mushrooms', x],
    ['Onions', 1],
    ['Olives', 1],
    ['Zucchini', 1],
    ['Pepperoni', 2]
   ]);

   var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
   'width':1000,
   'height':750};
   var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
   chart.draw(data, options);
   }
  </script>
 </head>
<body>
<!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
<div id="chart_div">
</div>
<div>
 <button onclick="drawChart()">draw</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem. I need to add these lines:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">
```

in the header. So all together

```
<HTA:APPLICATION ID="Test Google Charts" 
    BORDER="thick" 
    BORDERSTYLE="complex"/>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">
```